# Xcode can't find cocoapods module

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I feel like this should be so simple yet I can't get this to work.

I simply downloaded a test project from github [here](https://github.com/NicholasBellucci/FatSecretSwift), and installed the required module 'CryptoSwift' from cocoapods.

[image]

I build the project and I just get riddled with errors:

[image]

I've cleaned the project, deleted and started over but I can't get this to work at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you open your project file or the generated workspace file? Make certain that you've opened the workspace instead of your project.

Comment: yes i opened the newly created .xcworkspace file

Comment: I'm not familiar with having sub-targets as you've done in your Podfile. Is this necessary? Perhaps comment them out for the time being...

Comment: Hmm. Just tried that, same outcome.

Comment: did you run pod install?

Answer (score 1):

Your **CryptoSwift** download framework is not compatible with your code. If you use swift 4, use the following version:

```
pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 0.7.1'
```

Swift 3:

```
pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 0.7.0'
```